# Python - How to find all pages on a website corresponding a certain pattern

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For example, I have a website `mywebsite.com`. There a lot of pages on the website, but I want to get only the following pages:

```
mywebsite.com/article1
mywebsite.com/article2
mywebsite.com/article3
```

Every page name starts with "article" and end with a number.

I suppose I should use `BeautifulSoup` and `re`. How can I implement those libraries?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want to know how many article pages you have right?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan I want to get their URLs.

Comment: If so, you could just stick an HTTP request in a while-loop and make a GET call to each page, and once you hit a 404, just stop.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan I thought there is more "intelligent" solution.

Comment: Define your use of the word "intelligent".

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan I would somehow implement `re` library. Because there's a pattern. And so there is no need to do a `while True` loop. Or maybe I really should just stick to your solution...

Comment: What would you use regex for in this case?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan there is a word `article` and a `\d` (digit). But I am unsure how to impement this, that's why I am asking the question.

Comment: So regex matches a pattern in text. I don't think you need to match anything in your case from what I understand.

Comment: Unless you already have a file full of URLs and you want to match on those. But I don't think that's the case for this.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan Alright. I'll stick to your solution then. If you'd write the comment as an answer, I'd submit it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your codebase or really understand your use-case. However, this is how I'll do it.

```
    # regex
    pattern = re.compile(r'article\d+')

    links = soup.find_all('a', href=pattern)

    article_urls = [link['href'] for link in links]
```

**Pattern** is creating a regex pattern that looks for the word article followed by one or more digits, this can be modified if you're not looking for "article".

**links** is using beautifulsoup to find all the HTML anchor tags which href matches the pattern defined above.

**article_urls** is creating a list which will store all the collected urls.

---

***However***, if you want a full implementation with BS & re, then this is it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_article_urls(base_url):
response = requests.get(base_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    pattern = re.compile(r'article\d+')
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=pattern)
    article_urls = [link['href'] for link in links]
    return article_urls
else:
    print("Oops! Couldn't get the cool stuff. Something went wrong.")
    return []

base_url = 'https://mywebsite.com'
article_urls = get_article_urls(base_url)
print("Here are some URLs you might like:")
for url in article_urls:
    print(url)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: I am trying to implement your code to my case. I have a website `https://traveler.gg`. I want to get all pages that correspond the following pattern: `3-new-redemption-codes-from-\d-\d-special-program`. Your program returns `['https://traveler.gg/3-new-redemption-codes-from-4-3-special-program/', 'https://traveler.gg/3-new-redemption-codes-from-4-3-special-program/', 'https://traveler.gg/3-new-redemption-codes-from-4-3-special-program/', 'https://traveler.gg/3-new-redemption-codes-from-4-3-special-program/']`. I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: The code above will not work, you'll have to loop through each item in the article section and extract the "href". There is no identifier for an article, so you can not just select each one without manually typing the article name which is pointless. So you'll have to extract the elements from a parent element which contains all of the articles.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't said one important detail. There are no links to `article`'s on `mywebsite.com`. You can visit articles by only typing their URL manually. (e.g. `https://mywebsite.com/article1`)

Comment: Yes at the bottom of the page there is a articles section. You'll have to learn how to extract the elements of that section and loop through each and extract the article url. If you're not sure let me know.